# Why GPS provider returns location updates while the device has no access to sky?

Tags: android, gps

I test my app on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (Android 4.0.3) and noticed strange behavior.

Both location providers and enabled, network and GPS. When the app gets `onLocationChanged` updates, some `Location` reports are from the Network provider, some from the GPS provider.

The strange thing is that I keep the tablet about 3 meters away from the nearest window. As far I known, in such conditions, GPS shouldn't be able to tune to the GPS satellites. So why GPS provider returns correct `Location` updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3m from window is no problem for a good GPS antenna, to receive a (bad) position. so the situation you described is not a guaranteed GPS shield.